# SD card formatting problems

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, raspberry-pi, sd-card, disk-utility

I'm setting up a Raspberry Pi 4 to run LAKKA (a retro gaming emulation system). I started by copying the image to a 64GB SD card using balenaEtcher, according to some instructions that I found online. That all seemed to go fine.

I then changed my mind because the guide recommended installing your ROMS onto an external drive, so I decided to load LAKKA onto a 32GB drive and use the 64GB drive for the games. So I stuck the 64GB drive into my mac and used the `diskutil eraseDisk Ex
FAT` command to wipe out the 64GB drive so that it could be used as an external storage drive. That seemed to work fine as well.

Now, the guide tells me to format the external drive as NTFS, which MAC won't do. So I want to put it back into my Windows 7 machine to format it as NTFS. Problem is, my Windows 7 machine doesn't see the disk at all. I'm not sure how to resolve this. Any advice?

Comment: Do not interchange terms like *"SD card"* with *"drive"* and/or *"disk"*.  A SD card is neither.  As to your predicament, a Microsoft OS will ignore a storage medium that does not have any filesystem that it recognizes, e.g. FAT or NTFS.  Zero out the first sector of the storage device to induce Windows to format the device.

Comment: This is a Windows 7 problem, recent Windows 10 versions should be able to handle such disks. See also https://superuser.com/questions/302539/windows-7-cant-see-exfat-partition-that-i-made-in-osx-disk-utility As Windows 7 is End of Life in less than 30 days upgrading is the recommended way anyway (still possible for free).